# Адаптация под разные устройства

Tags: css, html5, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

сверстал сайт, версткой занимаюсь не так давно, на широких экранах выглядит довольно прилично, но вот с мобильными у меня проблема, не могу увеличить шапку сайта на весь экран, ей постоянно что-то мешает, но не могу понять что, хелп ми)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

@media (max-width:1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 970px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 500px;
  }
  .cont {
    max-width: 700px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:560px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
  #cont {
    max-width: 300px;
  }
  .cont {
    max-width: 400px;
  }
}

@media (max-width:390px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 250px;
  }
  .cont {
    max-width: 420px;
  }
}

#h5 {
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

td {
  color: #007BFF;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
}

.date {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body style="overflow-x: hidden;">
  <div class="cont" style="background: #343A40; height:56px; width:100%">
    <h4 class="col-1" style="float:left; padding: 10px 50px; color: white">НЛК</h4>
    <h5 id="h5">Портфолио</h5>
    <h5 id="h5">Рейтинг</h5>
    <h5 class="col-1" id="h5">Помощь</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="cont" style="float:left; width: 100%; height: 400px;background: #E9ECEF;padding: 0px 10px">
    <h1 style="padding: 55px 55px 0px">Портфолио</h1>
    <p style="padding: 0px 55px 0px 55px">Это место, где собраны ваши научные публикации. Здесь вы можете добавлять свои научные работы, получать информацию об их уникальности и смотреть отзывы ваших научных руководителей.</p>
    <button type="submit" style="margin: 0px 55px; width: 201px;height: 48px;flex-shrink: 0; border-radius: 4px;background: #007BFF; color:aliceblue; border-color: #007BFF;">Добавить работу</button>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="float:left">
    <div class="container" style="float:left; width: 445px;height: 250px; margin: 50px 55px; border:1px solid rgba(165, 164, 164, 0.582);">
      <div class="container" style="border:1px solid rgba(165, 164, 164, 0.582);background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.363);width: 445px;height: 48px;position:relative; left:-13.5px">
        <p style="padding:15px 30px; color: #000;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: normal;">Ваш профиль</p>
      </div>
      <h5 style="padding: 14px 20px;color: #000;
          font-family: Roboto;
          font-size: 20px;
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
          line-height: normal;">Сергей Павлович Фролов</h5>
      <p style="padding: 0px 20px"><b>Научная степень</b>: Магистр.<br> <b>Специализация</b>: Инвестиционные проблемы экономически развивающихся рынков.</p>
      <button type="submit" style="margin: 0px 20px; width: 140px;
          height: 38px;border-radius: 4px;background: #007BFF;color: #FFF;font-family: Roboto;font-size: 16px;font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;line-height: normal;border-color: #007BFF;">Редактировать</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container" style="float:left; width: 445px;height: 250px; margin: 50px 55px; border:1px solid rgba(165, 164, 164, 0.582);">
      <div class="container" style="border:1px solid rgba(165, 164, 164, 0.582);border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;background: rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.363);width: 445px;height: 48px;position:relative; left:-13.5px">
        <p style="padding:15px 30px; color: #000;
            font-family: Roboto;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: normal;">Статистика</p>
      </div>
      <p style="padding: 14px 20px;color: #000;
          font-family: Roboto;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-style: normal;
          line-height: normal;Line-height:30px"><b>На платформе</b>: 2 года.<br> <b>Добавлено работ</b>: 10.<br> <b>Средняя уникальность</b>: 75%.<br> <b>Языки работ</b>: русский, английский.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="float:left; margin: 0px 55px">
    <table id="navbar" class="table table-bordered" style=" width:100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Название работы</th>
          <th>Дата загрузки</th>
          <th>Научный руководитель</th>
          <th>Уникальность</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Привлечение инвестиций как фактор развития экономики</td>
          <td class="date">21.05.2019</td>
          <td>Асаншоева А.М.</td>
          <td>89%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>The role of accounting in sustainable development</td>
          <td class="date">11.02.2019</td>
          <td>Шаляпина В.С.</td>
          <td>78%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Сценарный анализ как инструмент учета рисков инвестиционного проекта
          </td>
          <td class="date">05.09.2018</td>
          <td>Васильев М.Г.</td>
          <td>67%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Глобальные и региональные инвестиционные тенденции</td>
          <td class="date">09.07.2018</td>
          <td>Асаншоева А.М.</td>
          <td>73%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Systemic risks in financial markets</td>
          <td class="date">18.05.2018</td>
          <td>Леонидов В.Б.</td>
          <td>77%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>The influence of tax regulation liberalisation on the domestic debt market</td>
          <td class="date">09.03.2018</td>
          <td>Шаляпина В.С.</td>
          <td>82%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Биткоин как новый вид инвестиций</td>
          <td class="date">29.01.2018</td>
          <td>Асаншоева А.М.</td>
          <td>71%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Проблема воспроизводства жилищного фонда в России</td>
          <td class="date">08.11.2017</td>
          <td>Васильев М.Г.</td>
          <td>65%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Влияние безработицы на экономику СНГ</td>
          <td class="date">17.09.2017</td>
          <td>Васильев М.Г.</td>
          <td>68%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Мировой валютный рынок Форекс</td>
          <td class="date">02.07.2017</td>
          <td>Васильев М.Г.</td>
          <td>67%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;height: 51px; background:#6361612f; float:left; margin-top: 50px;">
    <p style="padding:0px 55px; position:relative; top:15px; color: #6C757D;font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: normal;">© Научный личный кабинет. Все права защищены</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

При ширине экрана 560px срабатывает медиавыражение, и шапка сайта становится шириной 400px и справа появляется белое пространство, занимающее оставшуюся ширину. У вас `.cont` имеет максимальную ширину экрана, медиавыражения для него вам не нужны, можете их удалить

```
@media (max-width: 560px)
.cont {
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Убрал, но ничего не поменялось, при ширине экрана в 520px и меньше справа от шапки нарастает белый пробел)

Comment: Это из-за таблицы, она больше ширины экрана

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bg-nav,
.bg-foot {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

.fs {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Doc</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 bg-nav">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">НЛК</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Портфолио</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Рейтинг</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Помощь</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 clss="card-title">Портфолио</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Это место, где собраны Ваши научные пуликации. Здесь Вы можете добавлять свои научные работы, получать информацию об их уникальности и смотреть отзывы Ваших научных руководителей.
          </p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить работу</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Ваш профиль</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2">Сергей Павлович Фролов</h6>
          <p class="card-text"><b>Научная степень:</b> Магистр.<br><b>Специализация:</b> Инвестиционные проблемы экономически развивающихся рынков.</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Редактировать</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Статистика</h5>
          <p class="card-text"><b>На платфоме:</b> 2 года.<br><b>Добавлено работ:</b> 10.<br> <b>Средняя уникальность:</b> 75%.<br><b>Языки работ:</b> русский, английский.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-sm fs">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Название работы</th>
            <th scope="col">Дата загрузки</th>
            <th scope="col">Научный руководитель</th>
            <th scope="col">Уникальность</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Привлечение инвестиций как фактор развития экономики</td>
            <td>21.05.2019</td>
            <td>Асаншоева А.М.</td>
            <td>89%</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>The role of accounting in sustainable development</td>
            <td>11.02.2019</td>
            <td>Шаляпина В.С.</td>
            <td>78%</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 bg-foot">
      <p class="text-white">&#9400;Научный личный кабинет. Все права защищены</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Вот так это можно реализовать.

codepen. https://codepen.io/darinka-poznyak/pen/qBQyrKZ
P.S. над css не парилась и особо не разукрашивала. Таблицу до конца не дописывала, так, 3 ряда для примера. На codepen удобнее смотреть. Также к тегу `<table>` можно добавить бутстраповский класс text-break, который сделает разрыв(перенос) слов, чтобы таблица сильно не растягивалась. Может визуально это будет не очень красиво... но, действенно